# KeyEvent in JavaFX (KeyPressed) cannot fixed

Tags: netbeans, javafx

i'm trying to build a JavaFX FXML Application and i have a TextField and i want when press `Enter Key` and the cursor is in the TextField that key will do something... i traied this code it has a mistake i couldn't fix it :

```
       @FXML
      private void onKeyTyped (ActionEvent ee) { 
     text1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
         public void keyt (KeyEvent evt) throws IOException{
          //do something
       }
        });
       }
```

So please help me and thanks :)

Comment: onKeyTyped is the listener method; that's where you specify what code you want to execute. Right now, when the key is typed, you're actually adding another listener to your field, rather than executing the code you want. Would also be nice to see the FXML code

Comment: get rid of the private void onKeyTyped (ActionEvent ee) { and put the text1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
         public void keyt (KeyEvent evt) throws IOException{
          //do something
       }
        }); in the initialize in your control class

Comment: no i can't beacause if i rid it it will not has a class thus cannot find the handel methode in the FXML file

Comment: does this fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the fx id in scene builder of the fxml file of the text field. This should get rid of the need for the "private void onKeyTyped (ActionEvent ee) {" Then in the initialize method in your control class for example MainControl you need to add the set on key pressed with the event handler
Here is an example of how that would look:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class MainControl implements Initializable {
@FXML
TextField text1;
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {// Initializes
                                                        // everything
    text1.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {// Keyboard                                             // commands
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("ENTER")) {
            //do something

    }   
    }
    });



}
}
```

I hope that this helps

Answer (score 1):

TextFiledEvent.class

```
public class TextFiledEvent extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TerminalTextField btn = new TerminalTextField();
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

TerminalTextField.class

```
class TerminalTextField extends TextField {

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    int sizeOfList = 10;
    int keyPoint;

    public TerminalTextField() {
        setField();
    }

    public TerminalTextField(String text) {
        super(text);
        setField();
    }

    private void setField() {
        setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode().isLetterKey()) {
                    setText(getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                    positionCaret(getLength());
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```